# Developing android application but logging is not there

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am first time developing an android app. Very new to this. I have the application compiled and when I hit run on eclipse, I am expecting to see the log message but it never shows there

```
 try {
     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

     for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
          // JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                           ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                           ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                           ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear"));

          //Get an output to the screen
          returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
     }
```

using log.i.

Comment: Do you look at LogCat or the console in eclipse? Logging from android will be displayed in the logcat only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click DDMS and make sure the emulator you're running is selected. And make sure you're on the LogCat tab. you can also search for "app: com.your.app.package"

just to make sure your message isn't messed up you might try doing something like Log.d("tag", "test"); Also i assume you've imported android.util.Log; since it compiles.

also maybe do something like

```
if(jArray != null) { Log.i("","not null"); } else { Log.i("", "null"); }
```

right before your for loop